# GitLab operations without providing password and user token

Tags: gitlab

I am able to upload, download, list projects and repositories using a private token.

Is it possible to do the same without a private token? Means user will provide username or email address alone...

Regard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to push to a repository without authentication first.
And it is not possible to pull from a private repository, again without authentication.

If you are not using a token or password, the only other alternative (for authentication) would be using a private/public pair of SSH keys, with the [public one registered to your GitLab account](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html#adding-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account).

---

The OP adds:

> Means when user x upload file using common login, want to display user x has committed the file and so on...is that possible

Commit authorship has nothing to do with push/pull remote access authentication.

For a user to be visible on a commit, all they need to do is set their `git config user.name` and `git config user.email`, and then do some commits.

Comment: Thanks...Suppose if i have a common login for all the users and when user  commits the transaction, i want to show which user has committed...Means when user x upload file using common login, want to display user x has committed the file and so on...is that possible